# lightning:buttonIcon causes "Invalid page"

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-buttonicon

I would like to use `<lightning:buttonIcon />` to my component, like so:

```
 <component>
     <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:delete" />
 </component>
```

But whenever I add it (like above), it destroys the whole lightning community and displays a white page that says 'Invalid Page'

I looked at the console and I am getting like:

> WARNING: An internal server error has occurred Error ID:
>   1937148564-29569 (-551601421)

How do you solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
<aura:component>
  <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:delete" alternativeText="Some text"/>
</aura:component>
```

As the documentation states that alternativeText is Required.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_buttonIcon.htm

Comment: This worked, thanks! But they could have provided a more descriptive error message.

Answer (score 0):

To use the `<lightning:buttonIcon />` you have to provide value for two required attributes **iconName** and **alternativeText**.

**iconName**:

> The Lightning Design System name of the icon. Names are written in the
>   format 'utility:down' where 'utility' is the category, and 'down' is
>   the specific icon to be displayed. Note: Only utility icons can be
>   used in this component.

**alternativeText**:

> The alternative text used to describe the icon. This text should
>   describe what happens when you click the button, for example 'Upload
>   File', not what the icon looks like, 'Paperclip'.

Check all attributes here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_buttonIcon.htm